# Pesky Fetch Error, no error messages, just program aborting.?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am having a really pesky js error, where I run through a foreach loop and call fetch for each member in an array, and it works 7/10 times and on the 8th my program just crashes with no debug information. I have wrapped everything in try's and just confused about what the issue is, about to jump to axios, but was wondering if anyone had an idea?

```
try {
      allCurrentPrompts.forEach(async (prompt, index) => {
        APIdata.bodyParams.message = prompt;

        async function fetchData(index) {
          // Construct the URL with the search parameter
          const url = new URL(endPoints.promptRefine);
          url.searchParams.append(
            "linkedin_id",
            APIdata.searchParams.linkedin_id
          );

          // Create the request body
          const requestBody = {
            message: APIdata.bodyParams.message,
            request: APIdata.bodyParams.request,
          };

          // Create the fetch options
          const fetchOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: APIdata.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
          };

          try {
            // Make the fetch call
            console.log(`Request ${index} with prompt ${prompt} sending...`);
            const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
            if (!response.ok) {
              console.log(`response not ok, ${index}`);
              throw new Error("Request failed with status " + response.status);
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            // Process the response data here
            console.log(
              `Here is the response data from the api call refine ${index}`
            );
            console.log(data);
          } catch (error) {
            // Handle any errors that occurred during the fetch call
            console.error(error);
          }
        }

        // Call the fetchData function
        fetchData(index);
        console.log(`Test: 1`);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

What ends up happening is I get responses for the first 7 queries, and then on the 8th the program just crashes. I Console log to confirm requests look good, but the responses never come, and then crash. Its almost like a timeout error or something?

Chatgpt suggested adding this, which I also tried:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
  console.error('Unhandled Promise Rejection:', event.reason);
});
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the try/catch 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Criticism .

Comment: I would look into promise.all instead of a forEach

Comment: Don't use `forEach` when working with async/await. It's almost never what you want. Use `for...of`. I also agree with the other comments, don't catch errors if you're not doing anything with it.